# How to start applications automatically when Windows starts with a time window

Tags: windows-xp, command-line, batch, boot, cisco-vpn-client

I would like to ask if there is any way of starting applications automatically when windows XP boots up, but approximately 1 minute after each other.

THe problem we are encountering is that we use Windows defualt "Run on startup" but we use it to run custom batch command and VPN client. The problem is, VPN client somehow prevents the batch command from executing properly so I would like to add a 1 minute window.

Basically:

1. Run batch command (this opens via a separate shortcut)
2. Wait 1 minute
3. Run VPN client

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use ping to fake a delay (each *successive* ping adds 1 second), so `-n 2` is 1 second, `-n 3` is 2 seconds, and so on

```
start "" mybatch.bat
ping -n 61 127.0.0.1
start "" vpnclient.exe
```

and use that as the startup batchfile, instead of the two programs you have now.
*start requires a supposedly optional title, but it seems to give more issues if you leave it out*

Comment: Hacky and elegant all at the same time

Comment: You can use 'sleep 60' as well

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I tried it out, however all I am getting is "Windows cannot find the file xxxx.bat" :/

Comment: Scratch the above, I just need to find out how to launch batch command in a separate window. Thanks though :)

Comment: So being unable to find out how to launch the command in a separate window, what I did was that I now run the batch command in cmd on startup, then run the vpn.bat (which contains the ping). Will see how it performs during the night and will update.

Thanks for the IP tip :)

Comment: @Nikolay, sleep is not available in XP

Comment: @SeanCheshire, thanks for enlightening! I did not know that.

Comment: I suggest you write a comment in that batch file, explaining why the ping is there - this is one of those hacks where your successor will scratch his head wondering what the ... you've been doing (and subsequently submit it to http://thedailywtf.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I use the free [Startup Delayer](http://www.r2.com.au/page/products/show/startup-delayer/) to reduce boot-up time under XP, it allows you to specify when programs start (either after a fixed delay, or when e.g. the CPU is idle).

Comment: Thanks for the tip as well, however as this a computer we use for running tests, we prefer to have as little programs installed as possible :)